# Closed form for matrix power sum involving product and transpose

Tags: matrices

Given square, conformable matrices $\mathbf{M}$, and $\mathbf{C}$, 
I'm looking for a closed form for

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \mathbf{M}^{i} \mathbf{C} \left(\mathbf{M}^{i}\right)^{T}.$$

Or, alternatively, 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \mathbf{M}^{i} \mathbf{C} \left(\mathbf{M}^{T}\right)^{i},$$

which I think is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Call the sum $S$. Then $S$ is a solution to the equation $MSM^T+C=S+M^{n+1}C(M^T)^{n+1}$. If $M$ is real and $C$ is Hermitian, the equation is known as a [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation). You may rewrite the equation as
$$
(M\otimes M-I)\operatorname{vec}(S)=\operatorname{vec}\left(M^{n+1}C(M^T)^{n+1}-C\right).
$$
Therefore, provided $\lambda_i\lambda_j\ne1$ for any two eigenvalues $\lambda_i,\lambda_j$ of $M$ (where $i$ and $j$ may be the same index), you may obtain $\operatorname{vec}(S)=(M\otimes M-I)^{-1}\operatorname{vec}\left(M^{n+1}C(M^T)^{n+1}-C\right)$.